# Numpy.gradient: how to input a set of observations and corresponding outputs?

Tags: python, numpy, gradient

I'm new to using numpy.gradient, and was wondering if there is a way given a set of observation values:

(x1, y1, z1)

(x2, y2, z2)

...

(xn, yn, zn)

with corresponding outputs

f(x1, y1, z1)

f(x2, y2, z2)

...

f(xn, yn, zn)

(where these pairs are generated through simulations, and we don't actually know the analytic map from (x,y,z)-->f(x,y,z)) to input these into numpy.gradient() and have the gradient of f with respect to (x,y,z) calculated numerically? I have been trying to find examples and understand the documentation but am still not sure on what input this method actually takes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that's a time series. And am I right that you want the derivative in time for all three components?

Comment: I should have been more specific -- these aren't with respect to time; these actually are parameters in a set of ODE's that are being simulated; at the end of the day there is a value, n, that can be estimated from simulating our ODE's a number of times for a specific parameter set, where n doesn't depend on time (well, at least not to an extent we care about), only on the parameter set we input. I'd like to find which parameters, when varied, lead to the largest changes in this n value. (replying to @user7784503)

Comment: An option would be to fit a function to the observations, then differentiate that function. A gaussian process would be cool since it can give you the uncertainty of the gradient (the derivative of a GP is another GP)

Comment: Is that a regular grid in space.? then maybe just finite differences method.